# Where is ROSJava code?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could someone please point me to the location where I can download the ROSJava packages to use for Java development in Eclipse?
Could you also explain exactly what I need to download/build to be able to use it?
Unbelievable how difficult and time consuming it is to obtain and use this software. Instructions on getting this set up is pitiful!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11360/where-is-rosjava-code?/) by [HIIS](https://answers.ros.org/users/1136/hiis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Get a local copy of the rosjava repository with this command:

```
hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/
```

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2011-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HIIS](https://answers.ros.org/users/1136/hiis/) on 2011-09-29**:
Thanks buddy! Could you tell me where I run it from?